# .NET email testing client

Tags: c#, email, smtp, smtpclient

There are times when an ASP.NET or other.NET app with System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient fails to send messages. It might be due to a recent server change, maybe the server now requires SSL, or the port changed, or it's a DNS issue, changed credentials, firewall, or new Anti-Malware definitions. Maybe the issue is specifically with GMail or AOL or another server type. To get closer to identifying the problem we can catch SmtpFailedRecipientException before SmtpException, then catch SocketException, and plain Exception last. That helps to narrow down the issue but it's still not specific enough.

I'm getting the itch to write a C# app that will allow an admin to test a number of permutations to see what works, using a table of common options as well as a UI to enter new params like port numbers or email address formats, etc. The result should be a specific result telling exactly what is wrong with the specs provided, or at least starting with "can't connect outside network", then "can't connect to remote host", or "host exists but can't connect to port", then "connected but can't authenticate", then "authenticated but 'something else failed'...".

But before I do this, I have to believe there's already some FOSS that's been written for us to build upon. Can anyone recommend such a beast? Thanks.

Comment: This question explicitly falls into the offtopic category of source/tool recommendations, so I voted to close, but I also voted it up because I definitely recognize the frequent need for such a tool. :-)

Comment: Yeah, I was on the edge of that myself. In this case I'm looking for information. Where else can I ask a million people for a codebase except in a site like this where anyone who has worked with the same tools has had the same problems? :) I could rephrase and say "how do I code a parameter driven solution to ...." and someone might refer to existing code, but that's not a good approach for anyone here. So I'm hoping the votes to close will be removed. Thanks.